# What happens behind the scenes when I do a repo sync?

Tags: android, git, repository

What happens behind the scenes when I do a `repo sync` in my Android repository?

Is it equivalent to `repo forall -c "git pull"` or maybe git fetch? Or does it do something more complex?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a description on [this page](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html#sync) of what `repo sync` does.  In the usual case it will be more like `git pull --rebase` than `git pull`.  To quote what that page says:

> #### How Repo synchronization works
>
> When you run repo sync, this is what happens:
>
> 1. If the project has never been synchronized, then repo sync is equivalent to git clone. All branches in the remote repository are copied to the local project directory.
> 2. If the project has already been synchronized once, then repo sync is equivalent to:
>
>    ```
>    git remote update
>    git rebase origin/branch
>    ```
>
>    where branch is the currently checked-out branch in the local  project directory. If the local branch is not tracking a branch in the remote repository, then no synchronization will occur for the project.
>
>    If the git rebase operation results in merge conflicts, you will need to use the normal Git commands (for example, `git rebase --continue`) to resolve the conflicts.
>
> The repo sync command also updates the private repositories in the `.repo/` directory.

Essentially the `git remote update` makes sure that your remote-tracking branches (including `origin/branch`) are up-to-date by running `git fetch origin`.  <sup><sub>(In fact, the behaviour of `git remote update` is more complex than that, and [depends on your git config](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html), but in a typical setup it'll run `git fetch [remotename]` for each of your remotes.)</sub></sup>  Then the `git rebase origin/branch` rewrites your `branch` by replaying all your commits that aren't present upstream onto `origin/branch`.