# how to pull specific repo for rebuilding android images?

Tags: git, android-source, repo

I've inhouse bitbucket server which hosts the vendor.git with our customizations.
I've updated the local_manifest.xml and have built fresh android images.
Now, someone has pushed some changes to our vendor.git and I want to pull those changes and rebuilt the android images to save hours of time.

How can I manually pull only the repos e.g. vendor, kernel,...?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088143/what-happens-behind-the-scenes-when-i-do-a-repo-sync) thread and tried doing `repo sync` but `git log` inside AOSP/vendor/ still doesn't show the latest commit and it tries to go and update all the index looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, when the remote is not pointing upstream. You could try adding remote to your local directory and point it to your bitbucket repo manually and rebuilding.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ cd aosp/vendor

user@ubuntu:vendor$ git branch -a
* (no branch)
  remotes/servername/master
  remotes/m/release -> servername/master

user@ubuntu:vendor$ git remote show origin
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

user@ubuntu:vendor$ git status
Not currently on any branch.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   ...

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ...

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

user@ubuntu:vendor$ git ls-remote --heads
fatal: No remote configured to list refs from.

user@ubuntu:vendor$ cat .git/config                         <-- note the url

user@ubuntu:vendor$ git remote add origin ssh://git@git.server.com:1234/servername/vendor

user@ubuntu:vendor$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ssh://git@git.server.com:1234/servername/vendor
  Push  URL: ssh://git@git.server.com:1234/servername/vendor
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master                  new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)

user@ubuntu:vendor$ git checkout master

user@ubuntu:vendor$ git pull

user@ubuntu:vendor$ git log --online --graph
```